# I have query to get data on an hourly basis for a day but want data on 5 min basis

Tags: db2

I have an DB2 SQL query which works fine to fetch data on and hourly basis but i am not able to convert it further to fetch data every 5 min

```
select 
count(1) as NO_ORDER,
TO_CHAR(lastupdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24') as HOUR_VALUE  
from orders 
where lastupdate > '2019-10-20 00:00:00.000' 
and lastupdate < '2019-10-20 23:59:59.000' 
group by TO_CHAR(lastupdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24')with ur
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the result desired?

Comment: Side note: Assuming `lastupdate` is a `TIMESTAMP` datatype, your date range is wrong.  You should be using an inclusive lower-bound, `>=`.  As it is, rows at exactly midnight on `'2019-10-20'` will be excluded, but rows with at least one microsecond will be included.  I'm also extremely suspicious of your upper bound, because you're excluding the entire last second of the day - you almost certainly want "before the next day", or `< '2019-10-21 00:00:00'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
TO_CHAR(lastupdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24')
```

to

```
TO_CHAR(lastupdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
```

you can easily get it down to a minute.

For 10 minutes you could cut off the last digit for the minute but five minutes is a little bit more tricky.

Keep     `TO_CHAR(lastupdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24')` 
and add `TO_CHAR(lastupdate, 'MI')` 
and use case statement to build groups like

```
case when substr(TO_CHAR(lastupdate, 'MI'),2,1) in (0,1,2,3,4) then 1
     when substr(TO_CHAR(lastupdate, 'MI'),2,1) in (5,6,7,8,9) then 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be another way

```
group by DATE(lastupdate), HOUR(lastupdate), MINUTE(lastupdate)/5
```